# Azure : Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, azure-functions, pyodbc

I've written this python script :

```python
import time
import json
import pyodbc
import textwrap
import datetime
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import os 

def default(o):
    """Converts our Dates and Datetime Objects to Strings."""
    if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
        return o.isoformat()


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP Database trigger function processed a request.')

    database_username = 'Lophios'
    database_password = '*******'

    # Load the Database Credentials.
    logging.info('Loaded Database Credentials.')

    # Grab the table name.
    table_name = 'filing_AAPL'  # Change this to your desired table name

    # Grba the Drivers.
    logging.info(pyodbc.drivers())

    # Create the full connection string
    connection_string = (
        f'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;'
        f'SERVER=lophios-server.database.windows.net,1433;'
        f'DATABASE=sec-filling;'
        f'UID={database_username};'
        f'PWD={database_password};'
        f'Encrypt=yes;'
        f'TrustServerCertificate=no;'
        f'Connection Timeout=30;'
    )

    # Create a new connection.
    try:
        cnxn: pyodbc.Connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    except pyodbc.OperationalError:
        time.sleep(2)
        cnxn: pyodbc.Connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

    logging.info(msg='Database Connection Successful.')

    # Create the Cursor Object.
    cursor_object: pyodbc.Cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    # Define the Query.
    upsert_query = textwrap.dedent("""
    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [dbo].[{table_name}]
    """.format(table_name=table_name))

    # Execute the Query.
    cursor_object.execute(upsert_query)

    # Grab the Records.
    records = list(cursor_object.fetchall())

    # Clean them up so we can dump them to JSON.
    records = [tuple(record) for record in records]

    logging.info(msg='Query Successful.')

    if records:

        # Return the Response.
        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=json.dumps(obj=records, indent=4, default=default),
            status_code=200
        )
```

I've been able to run it locally but when I deploy it to my function app on azure and try to Test/Run I get this error: "HTTP response code 500 Internal Server Error". When I go to Monitor to see the invocation details I get:

```
Result: Failure Exception: Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 479, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 752, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "/home/site/wwwroot/sec_http_trigger/__init__.py", line 46, in main cnxn: pyodbc.Connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, when I'm looking for Network/Connectivity Troubleshooter I got this result:

```
Network connectivity tests to common Function App dependencies failed.
Network connectivity test to Azure storage endpoint configured in app setting "AzureWebJobsStorage" failed.
Connection attempt to the Blob Storage account resource configured for connection "AzureWebJobsStorage" failed. (This is preview feature)
Network connectivity test to the Azure storage endpoint configured in app setting "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING" failed. This can result in the Function App not starting up.
Connection attempt to the File Share Storage account resource configured for connection "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING" failed.
```

Here is my local.settings.json file:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sechttptriggerd7043c;AccountKey=98HrxSUQ8e7jjCTb/Fga5LwF3Bk+Lxy67UV6p7ix+g8EjnRsHh/h2hxjidcRM08TA3zvnv/G911j+AStrVMlIw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "connectionstring" : "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=tcp:lophios-server.database.windows.net;PORT=1433;DATABASE=sec-filling;UID=Lophios;PWD=******"
  }
}
```

my requirements.txt file

```
azure-functions
pyodbc
```

Here is my AzureWebJobStorage configuration :

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sechttptriggerd7043c;AccountKey=98HrxSUQ8e7jjCTb/Fga5LwF3Bk+Lxy67UV6p7ix+g8EjnRsHh/h2hxjidcRM08TA3zvnv/G911j+AStrVMlIw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

and my WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING :

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=sechttptriggerd7043c;AccountKey=98HrxSUQ8e7jjCTb/Fga5LwF3Bk+Lxy67UV6p7ix+g8EjnRsHh/h2hxjidcRM08TA3zvnv/G911j+AStrVMlIw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net
```

I've also checked Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in the CORS Panel and add my url function app to "allowed origins".

I'm on MacOs ARM64 processor, I don't think this information is relevant because I'm trying to make it work on my azure portal but I put this here since I've had some trouble with brew and the installation of PYODBC but I used Rosetta and now everything works locally.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced in my environment I also got the similar error.
as shown below:

[image]

To resolve this issue, you need to Use 17 version instead 18 in your code.

```
 f'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
```

My Connectionstring:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:odbcpy.database.windows.net,1433;Database=pythonodbc;Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;
```

As you can see below it worked for me.

This is my simple code to get the **SYSTEM_USER**:

```
import azure.functions as func
import pyodbc
import logging
import os

 
def sql_result(query):
      
    try:
        Connectionstring = os.environ["connectionstring"]
        with pyodbc.connect(Connectionstring) as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(query)
                result = cursor.fetchone()  # Fetch the result
                return result[0] if result else None
                
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        logging.error(f"SQL query failed: {e}")    
        

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    
    system_user = sql_result("SELECT SYSTEM_USER;")
    logging.info("SYSTEM_USER: %s", system_user)

 

    return func.HttpResponse(f"SYSTEM_USER: {system_user}", status_code=200)
```

I am importing my Connection string value from My **local.settings.json** in local environment.

**local.settings.json**

```
 {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "connectionstring": "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:odbcpy.database.windows.net,1433;Database=pythonodbc;Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;" 
  }
}
```

In Azure, I have added its value in.
**My function->environment variables-> app setting.**

[image]

if you are importing value of connection string from app setting its value should be same in **[" < name >"]**

```
os.environ["connectionstring"]
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for you response, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. When I'm trying to execute your code in my Azure portal I get HTTP response content : "SYSTEM_USER: None" which means that the connection to my database failed.
Also, I get the same error when I try to Test/Run (with ODBC Driver 17 or 18) and when I'm looking for Network/Connectivity Troubleshooter. I tried to modified my local.settings file as you did and even put my server and db to the same resources group but nothing seems to work.